# How to get a menu when fired a long click in ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, onlongclicklistener, android-adapterview

I have an adapter class in android to adapt images. I want to add an onLongClickListener() in it to inflate menu. But now it is not working i can't find the problem here please help me to fix this

**adapter class**

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,
            ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;
        Button btnClose;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,
                false);

        imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose = (Button) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        imgDisplay.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                ((Activity)_activity).openContextMenu(v);
                return true;
            }
        });
        ImageLoader2 imageLoader = new ImageLoader2(_activity);       
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(_imagePaths.get(position), imgDisplay);

        // close button click event
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _activity.finish();
            }
        }); 

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        _activity.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        //menu.setHeaderTitle(getString(R.string.menu_context_title));
        MenuInflater inflater = _activity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.grid_view, menu);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about_id:
            // do something useful
            return true;
        default:
            return _activity.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

}
}
```

Comment: Firstly, in `Java` fields are prefixed with an 'm'. E.g, mWidth, mAverage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. A `ContextMenu` is a floating menu that appears when the user performs a long-click on an element or any `View`. I decided to take the root `View`, for my convenience. You can adjust the code to suit your needs.

```
View view;
view = this.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

You must register each `View` that you want to have associated with the `ContextMenu`.

```
registerForContextMenu(v);  // I think you missed this
```

You then need to override the `onCreateContextMenu()` to create the menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");
}
```

And override `onContextItemSelected()` to preform the action when an option is selected from this menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   if(item.getTitle()=="Action 1") {
      function1(item.getItemId());// just place holders you can replace them with your functionality
    }
    else if(item.getTitle()=="Action 2") {
      function2(item.getItemId());// just place holders you can replace them with your functionality
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```